# vector_base inheritance vs composition

Tags: c++, stl

Short Question:

Is there a reason why C++ STL implementations use a `vector_base` struct/class (to handle resources and allocators) as a **base class** of `std::vector` rather than using **composition**?

Longer Version:

In my "quest" to improve my knowledge of C++ I've been trying to re-implement a `Vector` class, mostly `std::` compliant. I think I've understood well enough why is sensible to use allocators and why you'd actually want all the memory handling in a separate class/struct (RAII and all that) but I fail to see why would we want `std::vector` to inherit from that class rather than having it as a private member. 
[LLVM](https://code.woboq.org/llvm/libcxx/include/vector.html) and [gcc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h) both use inheritance for example.
I find, on the other hand, that constructors and assignments operators (especially the `move`-types) are much easier to handle using composition.

Am I only exposing my superficial knowledge of the language?

As an example I searched through some textbook and I found that Stroustroup's books have different versions of his "mock re-implementations" of the standard (just to confuse me more!) with his 2013 book "The C++ Programming language, 4th ed." using composition and his 2014 "Programming: Principles and Practice, 2nd ed." using inheritance!

Anyone  can help me shed some light?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

libc++ uses *private* inheritance and libstdc++ uses *protected* inheritance.

Protected and private inheritance is largely a [syntactic variant of composition](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance).

Comment: So it's essentially a matter of "preference"? 
I understand that it makes sense to have only one vector_base for each vector and private inheritance sort-of forces that .. maybe I just have a problem with move constructors!

Comment: @FooBant yes I would say it's a matter of preference.

Comment: @FooBant Likely not in this case, but, generally, if the base is _empty_ (has no non-static member variables), then inheritance may be preferred for _empty base optimization_. (Since C++20, `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute may have the same effect even with composition.)

Comment: @DanielLangr in this case the oposite is true. The main class (vector) adds no data members of its own, so it is a zero thickness wrapper around the privately-inherited implementation.

Comment: @n.m. Agree. I just wanted to show a possible reason one might (not in this case, but in a case of empty base) prefer inheritance over composition. Just for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.stroustrup.com/except.pdf

> Experience revealed that writing correct exception-safe code using explicit try-blocks
> is more difficult than most people expect. In fact, it is unnecessarily difficult because
> there is an alternative: The ‘‘resource acquisition is initialization’’ technique can be
> used to reduce the amount of code written and to make the code more stylized. In this
> case, the key resource required by the vectoris memory to hold its elements. By providing an auxiliary class to represent the notion of memory used by a vector, we can
> simplify the code and decrease the chance of accidentally forgetting to release it:

```
template<class T, class A= allocator<T> >
struct vector_base{
  A alloc; / / allocator
  T* v; / / start of allocation
  T* space; / / end of elements, start of space allocated for possible expansion
  T* last; / / end of allocated space
  vector_base(const A& a, typename A: :size_type n)
    : alloc(a) , v(a.allocate(n)) , space(v+n) , last(v+n) { }
  ˜vector_base() { alloc.deallocate(v,last-v) ; }
};
```

So it seems that the use of a RAII-base-class makes it easier for the various methods to correctly handle exceptions. They don't have to write `try/catch` everywhere.